# System.Text.Json.Serialization. Serialize string property as raw value

Tags: json, .net

Is it possible to serialize string property value as "raw" text, not as string with double quoutes (that naturally happens).

```
public class Demo
    {
        public int IntValue { get; set; }
        public string StrValue { get; set; }
        public string RawValue { get; set; }
    }

 Demo obj = new Demo { IntValue = 1, StrValue = "abc", RawValue = "{\"intProp\": 123 }" };
 string result = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
{
   "IntValue":1,
   "StrValue":"abc",
   "RawValue":"{intProp: 123 }"
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
   "IntValue":1,
   "StrValue":"abc",
   "RawValue": {intProp: 123 }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you change `Demo` Object at all? eg by making `RawValue` a `JsonObject` ?

Comment: @Jamiec, sorry, I can't :(  This field is populated outside as string

Comment: Ok, how about do you have access to the code so you could put an attribute on the `RawValue` property?

Comment: Yes, I can change Demo class except changing RawValue property type. Adding attributes to property is ok.

Comment: Ok, great so the answer linked above gives you everything you need then.